# How to get ButtonDrawable of a checkbox in API 21?

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

I have set a vector drawable in **`android:button`** attribute of my checkbox:

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    ...
    android:button="@drawable/avd_urgent"
    ...
/>
```

Now I want to get this drawable in my code and animate it:

```java
urgentChbx.setOnCheckedChangeListener((view, isChecked) -> {
    ((Animatable) urgentChbx.getButtonDrawable()).start(); // available only in API 23 and above
}
```

but `getButtonDrawable()` method is accessible only in API level 23 and above. How can I get the button drawable in API level 21?

Comment: The `getButtonDrawable()` method should be available in `AppCompatCheckBox` no matter the current API level (provided you're using a recent-enough library version). Have you declared `urgentChbx` as an `AppCompatCheckBox`, or just a `CheckBox`?

Comment: @MikeM. I changed my variable type to `AppCompatCheckbox` (in the layout, it was already `<...AppCompatCheckbox>`) and still encounter this exception when I run the app in lollipop: **No virtual method...**.  
The IDE also (still) prompts that `getButtonDrawable()` requires minAPI 23.

Comment: I am using the latest version of androidx and material support libraries

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I misread the docs earlier. It's actually a static method in a helper class. `AppCompatCheckBox` still extends the regular ol' `CheckBox`. You want to use `CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonDrawable(urgentChbx)` instead of `urgentChbx.getButtonDrawable()`.

Comment: @MikeM. Great! Thank you. Please add it as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: Oh, I'm good. :-) It was just a quick pointer. There's probably a duplicate around here somewhere, but I'm too lazy to search right now. Please feel free to post an answer yourself, if you like, or to just delete this, if you'd rather. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Mike M. in comments, use `CompoundButtonCompat.getButtonDrawable(urgentChbx)` to get the button drawable of your checkbox.